# Typescript generics, unknown nested function param

Tags: typescript, generics

i have som problem with generic function which has function with unknown param as param.

```
export const inject = <I,V>(fn:<U>(input?:U) => V, resolveWithPayload: boolean, resolveArgs?: I) => <R>(payload:R):R => {
    resolveWithPayload ? fn(payload) : resolveArgs ? fn(resolveArgs) : fn();
    return  payload;
};

const fn = (value:number):number => {
    propertyToMutate = value;
    return propertyToMutate;
}

const res =_fish.inject(fn,false,60)(50);
but calling it ends with :
```

> Argument of type '(value: number) => number' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '(input?: U) => number'.   Types of parameters
>   'value' and 'input' are incompatible.     Type 'U' is not assignable
>   to type 'number'.

if i change code this way:

```
export const inject = <I,V,U>(fn:(input?:U) => V, resolveWithPayload: boolean, resolveArgs?: I) => <R>(payload:R):R => {
    resolveWithPayload ? fn(payload) : resolveArgs ? fn(resolveArgs) : fn();
    return  payload;
};
```

it ends by type definition error in inject itself like:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'R' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'U'.
>
> TS2345: Argument of type 'I' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'U'.

So what can i do, if i dont know type of input of "fn" ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is caused because inject expects a function with signature `<U>(input?: U) => V`, but the one you provided has signature `(value: number) => number`. In other words, `inject` expects that `fn` is a generic function over the type `U` that accepts a parameter of type `U | undefined`, but the `fn` that you pass to it accepts a parameter of type `number`.

It's hard to know what exactly you're trying to accomplish with all of these generics, but perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
export const inject = <U>(fn:(input?:U) => U, resolveWithPayload: boolean, resolveArgs?: U) => (payload:U):U => {
    resolveWithPayload ? fn(payload) : resolveArgs ? fn(resolveArgs) : fn();
    return payload;
};

const fn = (value:number = 0):number => {
    propertyToMutate = value;
    return propertyToMutate;
}
```

Notice that `number` is the only required type parameter

Comment: ok thx, now i see, i was wrong with infer fn:<U>(input?:U), its not infer value of U only, but also generic function as input expectation. I have one question here, is there any sense with <T extends any>, why not only <T> ?

Comment: @OndrejBasista Sorry, my editor is usually configured to support React/tsx, which has trouble parsing generic lambdas (as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4922)). I used that syntax only while testing my solution and forgot to remove it. I have updated my answer for consistency.

Comment: ok thx, and i have another note here, if we use only one generic U, i think result U will be in both  returns not payload type, but first infer of U type, which is in this case number cause of fn function return type..

Comment: @OndrejBasista I'm not sure how you intend `inject` to work, but you ignore the return value of `fn`, it could be `(input?:U) => void`. You call it either with `payload` or or `resolveArgs`, so you could write it as `<U, V>(fn:(input?:U|V) => void, resolveWithPayoad:boolean, resolveArgs?:U) => (payload:V) => V` -- but this isn't quite 'natural' for type inference, so you may end up having to explicitly specify your type arguments whenever you call it.